# How to check if directory is writeable by UID?

Tags: perl, file, permissions, rule, file-find

Can `File::Find::Rule` be used to determine if a directory is writeable by a given UID?

I have used the following test:

```
my $uid = 123; # or whatever...

my @subDirs = File::Find::Rule->permissions(isWriteable => 1, user => "$uid")->directory()->maxdepth(1)->in( $dir );
if (scalar @subDirs == 0) {
    die "$dir is not writeable...";
}
die "$dir is writeable";
```

But it always returns that the `$dir` is writeable, even for test directories that I know are restricted.

What adjustments can I make to this test to make it work?

**EDIT**

Using `use File::Find::Rule qw(permissions)` caused the script to crash. I have not ever needed to specify this option with previous usages of `permissions()` in older `File::Find::Rule` operations.

If I adjust the rule as follows, I get things working.

Here, I am testing for the presence of the parent directory in the subdirectory list:

```
my @subDirs = File::Find::Rule::Permissions->directory()->permissions(isWriteable => 1, user => "$uid")->maxdepth(1)->name(".")->in("$dir");
```

The parent directory of the subdirectories of `$dir` is `.`

And if that directory exists in the list of `@subDirs`, it must be writable.

Thanks to ikegami for suggesting this module.

Comment: hum... [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule) doesn't have a `permissions` method.

Comment: Ah, you must be using [File::Find::Rule::Permissions](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule::Permissions).

Comment: Works fine for me (provided you `use File::Find::Rule ':permissions'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I test for the presence of the parent directory in the subdirectory list:

```
my @subDirs = File::Find::Rule::Permissions->directory()->permissions(isWriteable => 1, user => "$uid")->maxdepth(1)->name(".")->in("$dir");
```

The parent directory of the subdirectories of `$dir` is `.`

If that directory exists in the list of `@subDirs`, it must be writable.